StoreKit 2 Xcode Manage Transactions - subscription purchased but "unfinished"?
I am using SubscriptionStoreView in conjunction with the modifiers .onInAppPurchaseCompletion, .subscriptionStatusTask, and .manageSubscriptionSheet to allow my users to choose from either a monthly or yearly subscription option. I do NOT have any Consumable, Non-Consumable, or Non-renewing Subscription options.
When testing via Xcode, I'm able to purchase either subscription option successfully. However, the transaction manager (Xcode -> Debug -> StoreKit -> Manage Transactions) shows my transactions as "Purchased" but with the State as "Unfinished". My .storekit options do NOT have things like "Billing Retry" enabled or any simulated StoreKit failures enabled. Why are my transactions "unfinished"????
Note: Per another StackOverflow post that I previously posted, another developer indicated that the new way to use StoreKit for auto-renewing subscriptions would be to just use SubscriptionStoreView with the modifiers that I listed above, so that purchasing and checking/listening for subscriptions would be automatic. I took this to mean that I do NOT need to listen for updates, check current entitlements for subscription info, or "finish" transactions. Is this not the case? If so, why are my transactions showing up as "unfinished"?

I'd recommend not to use a SubscriptionStoreView yet.
There will be an extended correspondence with reviewers, which will take a lot of time, as they have not yet established a testing process for the release version of the app that uses SubscriptionStoreView.
upd Regarding a transaction finish: yes it has to be done manually by a developer.
You can add swiftui modifier per every subscription:
        .currentEntitlementTask(for: subscriptionStringId, priority: .userInitiated) { state in
            guard let transaction = state.transaction, case .verified(let verified) = transaction else {
                //...
                return
            }
            await verified.finish()
            //... actions that enable the features
        }


Currently, I'm planning on sticking with SubscriptionStoreView since this seems to be the easiest way to handle things in my particular situation. However, I appreciate you answering this because that's exactly what I was thinking. If I do have to revert back to the previous way to do this, I now know the proper way to finish a transaction :)

@KatM anyway within the app submission don't forget to mention that a reviewer first have to enable subscriptions and then wait some time before starting IAP checking. Because they expect that subscriptions' descriptions are there immediately but they are not of course in case of release version of  SubscriptionStoreView

Good idea! I will definitely mention that. Thanks!
